# Nested ng-repeat $first and $last?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following form,

```
<tbody ng-repeat="attGroup in attributesGroups">
    <tr>
        <td class="vcenter text-right">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:" ng-click="!$last && updateGroupOrder(attGroup.id,'down')" title="move down"><i class="entypo-down-open-big"></i></a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:" ng-click="!$first && updateGroupOrder(attGroup.id,'up')" title="move up"><i class="entypo-up-open-big"></i></a>                
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="att in attGroup.attributes">            
        <td class="vcenter text-right">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:" ng-click="!$last && updateAttributeOrder(att.id,'down')" title="move down"><i class="entypo-down-open-big"></i></a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:" ng-click="!$first && updateAttributeOrder(att.id,'up')" title="move up"><i class="entypo-up-open-big"></i></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

You see I am using $last/$first both in attributesGroups ng-repeat and attributesGroups.attributes ng-repeat. Now my question is that the second $last and $first is belong to attributesGroups  or attributesGroups.attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$first/$last` depends on the context where it is being called .

```
<tbody ng-repeat="attGroup in XXX">
    <tr>
        <!--- HERE $first/$last belongs to XXX --->
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="att in YYY">            
        <!--- HERE $first/$last belongs to YYY --->
    </tr>
</tbody>
```